# UML tools for Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, modeling, tool-uml

I'm using Eclipse Helios as IDE, specifically I am using the "modeling" version that may have all modeling plugins pre-installed.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to find a compatible version of UML2 tools.
I've downloaded both mdt-uml2-Update-3.2.0RC3 and mdt-uml2tools-Update-incubation-0.9.0 but I can't install UML2 tools because I got some dependencies errors.

Do you know which version of Eclipse has a full support for UML2 and Modeling tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's true the UML2 Tools project is not active anymore, and will not be part of Indigo.
However, the UML2 project providing the UML2 reference implementation is still active and is used as a basis by the MDT-Papyrus project which is now the "standard" UML2 tool as part of the Modeling bundles. I know, quite confusing!

Answer (score 1):

UML2 tools does not have a Helios-compatible release. You could use instead the new Papyrus UML tool available from the Modeling Component Browser component or from http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/

Answer (score 1):

UML2 tools was stopped last year after the take over of Borland. Concerning open source projects only Papyrus and Topcased are available for Helios.